# Linear Layout - Buttons Disappear

Tags: android, android-layout

Consider the following XML layout with one scrollable TextView and two Buttons below it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
            />   


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


       <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button2"
       />


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView is updated dynamically. The buttons show up nicely if the TextView content fits on the screen. However as soon as the TextView content exceed screen size to use a scrollbar, the bottom buttons disappear.

How to ensure that buttons show up always,  scrollbar or no scrollbar ?

Comment: you can keep your textview and linearLayout of button in a scrollview.

Comment: thnks but I want the button to be always visible and only the Textview to be scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting maxHeight:

```
android:maxHeight="480dp"
```

check the screen size and dynamically set the `maxHeight`

Answer (score 0):

set Layout weightSum="2" to the linear layout, layout_weight to each button to 1

```
android:weightSum="2" // to the layout

android:layout_weight="1" // to each the button
```

Also your **android:orientation="horizontal"** is **horizontal**, which is default, maybe you want to be **vertical**, (just saying)...

**EDIT** Remove the scrollbar attributes and wrap the textView in a ScrollView.

Comment: weightSum is **optional**. But setting it is not harmful.

Comment: this is not what i am looking for :(. my question has nothing to do with weights